# Advent of Code 2021: day 1

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

I am doing the Advent of Code challenge to learn Rust (obviously there may be spoilers if you still want to do the challenge).

The instructions are too long to include verbatim so I will [link them](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/1) and give a summary for the two parts.

In part 1, the programme must compare a user-provided list of integers and count every time the number is bigger than the previous one. The output is the total number of increases.

In part 2, the programme is modified to compare the sum of the last three numbers with the previous sum.

I am particularly interested in how I can write more idiomatic Rust. Whenever I ran into an error, I just hacked at it until it stopped complaining but I'm sure there's a better way. Some tips that I'm looking for (but not limited to) are:

- When to use mutators and when not to.
- How to handle errors better.
- Boiler-plate code removal and style tips

Please include an example of the right way to do something. I can tell that I've taken more liberties than I need to with certain parts but I don't know what a better way looks like. So just telling me that something is wrong might not help.

## Part 1

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::env;


fn main() {
    let mut count: u16 = 0;
    let mut last: u16 = 0;
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = args.get(1).unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Please provide file name"));

    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Couldn't open file {}", filename));
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.trim().is_empty() {continue;}

        if last < line.parse().unwrap() && index != 0 {
            count += 1;
            println!("{} (increased)", line);
        } else {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
        last = line.parse().unwrap();
    }
    println!("Increase count: {}", count);
}
```

## Part 2

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::env;


fn main() {
    let mut count: u16 = 0;
    let mut curr:Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
    let mut last:Vec<u16> = Vec::new();

    //--------
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = args.get(1).unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Please provide file name"));
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Couldn't open file {}", filename));
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    //--------

    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.trim().is_empty() {continue;}

        last = curr.to_vec();
        curr.push(line.parse().unwrap());
        if curr.len() > 3 {
            curr.remove(0);
        }
        let curr_sum:u16 = curr.iter().sum();
        let last_sum:u16 = last.iter().sum();

        if last_sum < curr_sum && index >= 3 {
            count += 1;
            println!("{} (increased)", line);
        } else {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
    println!("Curr: {:?}", curr);
    println!("Last: {:?}", last);
    println!("Increase count: {}", count);
}
```

Comment: Please summarise the _objective_ in the question title and description, so that the question has value even when the linked resource is not accessible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use rustfmt (easily done project-wide with `cargo fmt`) to give your source files consistent formatting. You might not like all of the changes it makes (neither do I) but when sharing code with other people it's more important to have predictable, consistent formatting. You'll get used to it, anyway.

### Part 1

```rust
    let mut count: u16 = 0;
    let mut last: u16 = 0;
```

These variables aren't used here. It's usually a good idea to declare variables with the smallest possible scope; in this case, right before the `for`.

Using `u16` is harmless in this program but doesn't really buy you anything in terms of size (the data will almost certainly be stored in 32- or 64-bit registers anyway), so I would prefer `u32` or `usize` for `count`, and `u32` or perhaps `i32` for `last` (I don't think the problem states the depths can't be negative). Note that `u16` is not big enough to solve the next day's problem.

```rust
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = args
        .get(1)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Please provide file name"));
```

When you have an iterator and you only need one item from it, use `nth` instead of collecting into a `Vec`. Use `&` to borrow the result if you need a reference like `get` returns.

`.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!(...))` is common enough there is a shortcut for it, `.expect(...)`.

```
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Couldn't open file {}", filename));
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
```

`expect` doesn't quite work here, since you want to add additional information to the error message (the filename). This is fine (for prototyping, at least; for libraries and user-facing errors, you'll probably want to handle errors in some way other than panicking, but for coding challenges, it's fine).

On the other hand, this way of reading files might be how you would do it if you were concerned about memory usage, but it's a bit cumbersome for quick scripts and coding challenges. Instead, you can use `std::fs::read_to_string` to slurp a whole file at once into a `String` and use `.lines()` on that.

```
    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
```

Starting at `last = 0` means you have to keep track of the `index` and check whether it is 0 on every iteration. What if you had an iterator over integers? Then you could set `last` initially to the first value in the iterator, and check as you iterate over the rest of them.

```
        if line.trim().is_empty() { continue; }
```

The input shouldn't have any blank lines in it. I would not check for this.

```
        last = line.parse().unwrap();
```

You already did `line.parse().unwrap()` a few lines above; why not store that in a variable and reuse it?

With all the above suggestions applied here's what I came up with for the first challenge program:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let filename = env::args().nth(1).expect("Please provide file name");
    let file =
        fs::read_to_string(&filename).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Couldn't open file {}", filename));

    let mut count: usize = 0;
    let mut lines = file
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.parse().expect("invalid number"));
    let mut last = lines.next().unwrap_or(0);
    for this in lines {
        if last < this {
            count += 1;
            println!("{} (increased)", this);
        } else {
            println!("{}", this);
        }
        last = this;
    }
    println!("Increase count: {}", count);
}
```

### Part 2

Most of what I mentioned for Part 1 will also apply here; however, the loop state is a bit more complex since you need to keep track of the previous length-3 window.

```
        last = curr.to_vec();
```

This line makes a clone of `curr` (note: `to_vec()` on something that is already a `Vec` is equivalent to `clone()`), *drops* whatever `Vec` was previously in `last` and replaces it with the newly cloned one. This means you're deallocating and reallocating a length-3 vector every iteration, which is a lot of heap churn.

```
        curr.push(line.parse().unwrap());
        if curr.len() > 3 {
            curr.remove(0);
        }
```

Similarly, here you lengthen the vector to 4, then remove from the beginning, which shifts the three end elements backwards by 1. Increasing the size of the vector can also cause reallocation (it probably does not in this case, but mostly by luck).

There are a few ways to approach this problem.

- You might have a buffer containing the previous 3 elements. At the beginning of each iteration, the buffer contains the last window; sum it up to get `last_sum`. Then replace the oldest element with the newest one and [`rotate_left`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_left) by 1. Now the buffer contains the current window; sum it up to get `curr_sum`. You don't need a second buffer to keep track of the other window. Note that you can initialize the window to `[0; 3]`
- You could instead use a `VecDeque` to store the buffer, combining `push_back` with `pop_front` (or vice versa). This means slightly less copying since the items do not need to be shifted, and it is flexible to runtime-determined window sizes. For a fixed window size of 3 it's probably overkill.

```
        let curr_sum:u16 = curr.iter().sum();
        let last_sum:u16 = last.iter().sum();
```

Calculating both the current and last sums each iteration means you're calculating each one (except the very first and very last sum) twice as often as necessary. You could make `last_sum` an extra state variable and just assign it to the value of `curr_sum` at the end of the loop.

#### A better algorithm?

In fact, even with that modification, you are still doing some extra work. Consider the example from the problem statement:

```
199  A      
200  A B    
208  A B C  
210    B C D
```

Window `A` and window `B` both contain the term `200 + 208`, but you calculate that twice. You can calculate window `B` from window `A` by adding the new number (210) and *subtracting* the old one (199). This by itself does not win any performance (with windows of size 3) since you replace only two additions with one addition and one subtraction. However, note that if you only care about whether the sum is increasing or not from window `A` to window `B`, the *center two* numbers are completely irrelevant: all that matters is whether, for this slice *of length 4*, the last number is greater or less than the first. If you could loop over windows of length 4, you could replace all the addition with a single comparison. This strategy also works for solving Part 1 (with windows of size 2).

In the standard library, the way to iterate over windows is to `collect` the iterator into a `Vec` and use the `windows` method. However, with the `itertools` crate, you can iterate over windows of an iterator directly using the `Itertools::tuple_windows` method. Either way is acceptable.

### About mutability

Personally I find nothing bad about the use of mutability in your original code. Mutable state is neither good nor bad, but it is complex, and so should be used when it is useful and minimized otherwise. The amount of mutable state in these algorithms can't really be reduced (except by changing the algorithm itself, as I outlined in the previous section). It is possible to rewrite code like this to use `scan`s and `fold`s and `for_each`es and eliminate (almost) all `mut`s. But I don't find that useful. Iterator combinators can be overused, too.

That's not to say that mutable state isn't ever overused - just, I don't think this code is an example of such overuse.

### Error handling

"How to handle errors better" is strongly dependent on context. As I mentioned earlier, `expect` & `panic!` are fine for coding challenges, prototypes, and tests; however, if you're writing a library you probably want to return errors with useful context that the caller can interpret, and if you're writing a binary you probably want to catch errors at some level and print nicely formatted messages. These desires can be at odds with each other, and there are other factors, which is why the Rust ecosystem has so many crates that help you deal with errors in one way or another.

A thing worth trying, if for no other reason than to become familiar with it, is to use the `?` operator to propagate errors up into `main` instead of using `unwrap` or `expect`. `main` may be defined as returning a `Result`, so you can even use `?` inside `main` itself (if you return an `Err` from `main`, the contents will be printed automatically, although maybe not in the most visually appealing way). Here's one possibility:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let filename = env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .ok_or_else(|| "Please provide a file name")?;
    let input = std::fs::read_to_string(filename)?;
```

`Box<dyn Error>` is a type that can be easily converted from most other kinds of errors, so it's good for prototyping. `Option::None` isn't an error, so I use `ok_or_else` to convert it into something that can be bubbled up with `?`. But `read_to_string` already returns a `Result` of an appropriate type, so `?` works on that directly.

The next step up is to create your own error type and define conversions `From` each of the error types you want to use with `?`. There are, as I mentioned, different ways to approach this problem space depending on your needs. `Box<dyn Error>`, as above, is a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough advice.

Comment: Out of interest, though, the empty line check is needed for some reason. Even your code seems to fail without something like `.filter(|line| !line.trim().is_empty())`

Comment: @LordRatte Did you copy and paste the input from a browser, or download the file directly? I think you probably introduced a blank line by mistake. The files on AoC don't have empty lines.

Comment: Perhaps that is it.